# Cache sitemap.xml in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I need to cache my /sitemap.xml page and refresh it every day. How can i implement this task in codeigiter3?
This is my function in Site class

```
public function sitemap() {
  header('Content-Type:application/xml');
  $data['movies'] = $this->site_model->getMoviesForSitemap();
  $this->load->view('site/sitemap', $data);
}
```

Comment: Cache db query in file and check if that file exists before making another db query.

Comment: how? thanks but im new in codeigniter and dont know cache at all

Comment: Answer screams itself: learne basic caching from PHP website then caching db data from CodeIgniter docs.

Comment: very helpful answer... I thought someone who knows how to write the code will write it here, i dont need the algorithm, i need code, code on codeigniter )) ok never mind, sorry...

Comment: You took it wrong. Nobody here writes code for free. But you didn't have a second thought of what I said. Your methodology is wrong. you don't need refresh cache every day. You need to delete old cache if exists on every insert or update into `sitemap_movies` (or what ever is called table) where are data you are getting with code above. And then use it 2 hours or 20 days if there is no changes (updates or deletes) doesn't matter. In code above you need to check first if such a file exists and get result from it first and if not, make selection as you do with creating it for next request.

Comment: "Nobody here writes code for free" really? LOL i see many answers with code examples on that website. If u do not want help so please dont write anything at all

Comment: i repeat i dont need the algorithm. Please if anyone familiar with codeigniter cache library help me and write code example here... for free. Otherwise what's the point in this site?

Comment: I meant don't expect someone writes you code block that way. You need to try it on your own, then if you get some error or unwanted result, you have to post it all - your attempt code, your result/error and describe wanted result. More of that can be found [here {How To Ask}](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) - article that helped me so much. Try and show some effort. Help us to help you.

Comment: LOL. so the problem is that I do not know how to write the correct code on codeigniter to implement cache. thats why i ask here for code. ok forget. how to delete this post with question? LOL

Comment: Wrong. Problem is that you don't read what I am writing. And regardless with that attitude of you - no try or effort at all? Good luck with that.

Comment: I wrote my code at the very beginning. and i asked how to implement cache. please do not come back here to my post.. let other people answer if they know how to implemet my task

Comment: And what did you try with [database caching class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html) that I left you in first comment which is btw in docs. Man, you resist to follow the docs. In that code you left there is no single character or line that showing you tried to cache something which gave you some error. Show me the error. Don't ask for code. Show the error you got.

Comment: can you write code to implement this?

Comment: Sure as soon as see error made by your effort. `@noErrorInCodeNoHelpProvided(true);`

Comment: i dont need database caching. just simple caching. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function sitemap() {
  header('Content-Type:application/xml');
  $data['movies'] = $this->site_model->getMoviesForSitemap();

  //Caché for 60 minutes
  $this->output->cache(60);

  $this->load->view('site/sitemap', $data);
}
```

And in your view you can put something like

```
<!--Created on <?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?>-->
```